# How to automatically link one template sheet to multiple sheets in excel?

Tags: excel

I have one excel sheet (template) with product prices and hundreds of sheets that refer to the template sheet.

My question is: how to **automatically** fill in the prices in all corresponding sheets?
It is important to me to keep all the data updated, for example when I change a value in the template file, the values should also change in the other worksheets.

I have to add that I often add new sheets and sometimes I have to edit sheet names too.

There is how those sheets and template sheet look like:

### *template sheet*

[image: template file]

### *example component sheet*

[image: example component sheet]

I was trying to use Microsoft Query, but it seems to crash when I add new files.
Maybe there's another way to link data from those sheets?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Vlookup or lookup or index with match.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/index-and-match